# Return functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, return

I'm using a function to get 2 values/variables. i can return one of them but not both? how do i go about being able to extract both to use elsewhere in the code?

My code is:

```
let lakes = {
    names: ['Caspian Sea', 'Tarn Hows', 'Crater Lake', 'Lake Tanganyika', 'Lake Vostok', 'Lake Baikal'],
    fathoms: [560, 530, 324, 803, 546, 897]
};

function calculateDepth() {
    var deepestLakeName = lakes.names[0];
    let deepestLake = lakes.fathoms[0];

    if (deepestLake < lakes.fathoms[1]) {
        deepestLakeName = lakes.names[1];
        deepestLake = lakes.fathoms[1];
        console.log('The deepest lake is: ' + deepestLakeName);
        //logged the statements to ensure the if statement was working

    } else if (deepestLake < lakes.fathoms[2]) {
        deepestLakeName = lakes.names[2];
        deepestLake = lakes.fathoms[2];
        //console.log('The deepest lake is: ' + deepestLakeName);

    } else if (lakes.fathoms[3] < deepestLake) {
        //code broke with previous deepestLake > lakes.fathoms system, so had to switch them around to get correct result
        deepestLakeName = lakes.names[3];
        deepestLake = lakes.fathoms[3];
        //console.log('The deepest lake is: ' + deepestLakeName);

    } else if (deepestLake < lakes.fathoms[4]) {
        deepestLakeName = lakes.names[4];
        deepestLake = lakes.fathoms[4];
        //console.log('The deepest lake is: ' + deepestLakeName);

    } else if (deepestLake < lakes.fathoms[5]) {
        deepestLakeName = lakes.names[5];
        deepestLake = lakes.fathoms[5];
        //console.log('The deepest lake is: ' + deepestLakeName);

    } else {
        //console.log('The deepest lake is: ' + lakes.names[0])
    }
    return deepestLake; // i can return this, but i also want to return the deepestLakeName so i can output both later on.

}
```

Thanks for any help and apologies if a similar thing has been asked elsewhere. i searched, but couldn't find anything with 2 specific values that need returning. i can manage 1, but not more..

Comment: return a tuple?

Comment: Return a tuple/object and add a comment about the API: `return {name: deepestLakeName, value: deepestLake}`.

Comment: `return { deepestLake: deepestLake, deepestLakeName: deepestLakeName };`

Comment: It's not `Python` @ASDFGerte, it's `JS` related. Btw, you can return an `object`.

Comment: @TheAlpha i was using [typescript wording](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) for something that works just aswell in vanilla JS. Especially along with destructuring.

Comment: Also, and I'm sorry if this is pedantic, but you aren't "return functions", you are returning values from functions.  Your title makes it sound like you want to return a function from a function, i.e. `function a() { return (b) => b + 1;}`.

Comment: apologies zero298, i will be clearer in future. You and Nicolas both suggested returning an object and that worked. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could returns an object with both property :

```
let lakes = {
    names: ['Caspian Sea', 'Tarn Hows', 'Crater Lake', 'Lake Tanganyika', 'Lake Vostok', 'Lake Baikal'],
    fathoms: [560, 530, 324, 803, 546, 897]
};

function calculateDepth() {
    var deepestLakeName = lakes.names[0];
    let deepestLake = lakes.fathoms[0];

    if (deepestLake < lakes.fathoms[1]) {
        deepestLakeName = lakes.names[1];
        deepestLake = lakes.fathoms[1];
        console.log('The deepest lake is: ' + deepestLakeName);
        //logged the statements to ensure the if statement was working

    } else if (deepestLake < lakes.fathoms[2]) {
        deepestLakeName = lakes.names[2];
        deepestLake = lakes.fathoms[2];
        //console.log('The deepest lake is: ' + deepestLakeName);

    } else if (lakes.fathoms[3] < deepestLake) {
        //code broke with previous deepestLake > lakes.fathoms system, so had to switch them around to get correct result
        deepestLakeName = lakes.names[3];
        deepestLake = lakes.fathoms[3];
        //console.log('The deepest lake is: ' + deepestLakeName);

    } else if (deepestLake < lakes.fathoms[4]) {
        deepestLakeName = lakes.names[4];
        deepestLake = lakes.fathoms[4];
        //console.log('The deepest lake is: ' + deepestLakeName);

    } else if (deepestLake < lakes.fathoms[5]) {
        deepestLakeName = lakes.names[5];
        deepestLake = lakes.fathoms[5];
        //console.log('The deepest lake is: ' + deepestLakeName);

    } else {
        //console.log('The deepest lake is: ' + lakes.names[0])
    }
    return {
        value: deepestLake,
        name: deepestLakeName 
    }; 

}

let newLakes = calculateDepth();
console.log(newLakes.value, newLakes.name);
```

Comment: apologies @zero298, i will be clearer in future. Nicolas, that did the trick. thank you very much